# string indices must be integers pandas datareader

Tags: python, pandas-datareader

```py
import pandas_datareader as pdr
df = pdr.DataReader('AAPL', 'yahoo', start='2020-01-01', end='2020-12-31')
```

Hi, im starting with pandas_datareader and im trying to understand how it works, so I made a pretty simple code and try to get info about any stock but when i run it throws me the "string indices must be integers" error, idk why, I also tried importing pandas first, but it turns out
the same, I would be very thankful if someone can help me.

PD: with or without print(df) it happens the same.

Comment: You should post the whole error with traceback

Answer (score 0):

The `pandas_datareader` library, which is used to download stock price data in the code was deprecated in version 1.2.0 of pandas and removed in version 1.3.0. If you are using a version of pandas that is newer than 1.2.0, the `pandas_datareader` library will not be available and you will need to use a different method to download stock price data.

You can try:

```
import yfinance as yf

df = yf.download('AAPL', start='2020-01-01', end='2020-12-31')
```